# Write a function that prints all of the whole numbers that an integer is divisible by

Tags: python

What I have so far is this, but I know this is not right:

```
n=8     
if n % 5 == 0:     
    print "divisible by 5"
elif n % 9 == 0:    
    print "divisible by 9"
elif n % 8 == 0:    
    print "divisible by 8"
```

Comment: Mind if I ask what the "if not..." Part does?

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 8
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if not n%i:
        print "divisible by", i
```

Comment: wouldn't range(1,(n+1)/2) be good enough? And count n as an automatic hit? In other words, past 4, 8 can only be divided by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def factor_list(n):
     for i in range(1,n+1):
          if n%i==0:
             print(i)
```

This method works by seeing if all the numbers up to n+1 are divisible by it:

so for n=8 it will loop and check 8/1, 8/2 8/3 ... 8/8 the key here is the modulo (%) operator. It calculates the remainder.

Logic: We say n is divisible by m - if (n%m) is equal to zero that is remainder is zero.

You can test this code, for all n, if you take 'n' from console input: n = int(raw_input())

Answer (score 0):

you need to go over each value from 2 up to sqrt(n) ... and see if it is divisble by that 
number ...

```
for i in range(2,int(sqrt(N))+1):
```

and check if something is divisible

```
is_divisible = number%divisor == 0
```

**note that all integers are divisible by 1 and them-selves

Comment: He's looking for whole number factors, not prime factors.  So if he only loops through `sqrt(n)`, he'd have to yield both integer factors `i` _and_ `n / i` (whenever `i` divides `n`), because he won't see the greater factor again.  And he'd have to verify that `n / i` is not equal to `i` to prevent yielding `sqrt(n)` twice when `n` is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

More code but faster for large numbers (because you don't have to check every number, just primes) is to get all of the prime factors of n and return the product of each set in the powerset of the factors.

```
import itertools as it
import functools
from operator import mul
from collections import Counter
import gmpy2 as gmpy

def prod(a):
    return functools.reduce(mul, a, 1)


def get_primes(upper_limit=None):
    if upper_limit:
        yield from it.takewhile(lambda x: x < upper_limit, get_primes())
        return
    prime = 2
    while True:
        yield int(prime)
        prime = gmpy.next_prime(prime)


def get_factors(n):
    factors = Counter()
    prime = get_primes()
    while n != 1:
        factor = next(prime)
        while not n % factor:
            n //= factor
            factors[factor] += 1
    return factors

# From here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


def get_divisors(n):
    factors = get_factors(n)
    ret = (prod(i) for i in powerset(factors.elements()))
    return set(ret)
```

`get_divisors(81)` returns `{1, 3, 9, 27, 81}`

Answer (score 0):

This would have looked like black magic to me when I started learning the language. Nonetheless;

For a given `n`, create the accumulator list `x`

```
n = 162; x=[]
```

then loop over the integers `i=2` up to `i=1+n/2` and add `i` to the list `x` if `n` is divisible by `i`:

```
for i in range(2,int(n/2)+1): x.extend(([],[i])[n%i==0])
```

or alternatively

```
for i in range(2,int(n/2)+1): x.extend([i]) if n%i==0 else []
```

the result is stored in `x`

```
print(x)
[2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 27, 54, 81]
```

All together:

```
n = 162; x=[]
for i in range(2,int(n/2)+1): x.extend(([],[i])[n%i==0])
print(x)
```

Explanation: [PEP 308](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)

Edit: using list comprehension, one could even make this a one-liner:

```
n=162; x=[]; x.extend([i for i in range(2,int(n/2)+1) if n%i==0]); print(x)
```